# mod_rewrite redirect loop / breaks my site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**What I want:**

- `/foo.php` display `/foo` in url bar
- `/foo` redirect to `/foo.php`
- Both must view `/foo.php`
- Must work with `/showthread.php?id=00` (`/showthread?id=00`) and such

I constantly get a redirect loop even if I use [L] everywhere.
I tried these:

```
(1)
RewriteRule ^/forums$ forums.php [R]
RewriteRule ^/forums\.php$ forums [PT]
(2)
RewriteRule ^forums\.php/?$ forums [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^forums/?$ forums.php
(3)
RewriteRule ^forums/?$ forums.php [L,R=301]
(4)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z/]+).php$ $1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Each of the above work for individually `foo.php` to `foo` or `foo` to `foo.php` but infinite loop on both.

I also tried this:

```
## don't touch /forum URIs
# RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ %1 [QSA,R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Which works as expected but breaks a lot of site features for some reason. (search bar does not work, forums don't work, login doesn't work)

I need `foo.php` to still work because MyBB uses it.

Comment: 2nd commented section is what you will need. Now you need to clarify what exactly are the problems with that code in place.

Comment: The commented code breaks MyBB forum post / thread actions / login / search and what not
I'm unsure why.
Though `/showthread?id=xx` works
My (temp) domain is mysteriousserver.tk

Comment: I now have that code in .htaccess

Comment: Just saying something breaks doesn't give enough information to debug. What full URL you entered in browser and what is the error you got?

Comment: If you use the search function nothing happens. If you post a thread it says `Can not upload file - Too large for php post_max_size directive. Please press the back button.` If you post a reply it says `There was an error posting your reply: The specified thread does not exist.` If you login you will still not be logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Still same issues with MyBB but the rewriting works. This is my htaccess:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=t11fNZGY

Comment: Do you have a snippet for a single page rewrite (both ways) that I can try?  I think MyBB doesn't like the full auto.

Comment: This is exactly the snippet for doing both redirect and rewrite. Instead of `([^.]+)` use `(single)` in 1st rule and replace `(.+?)` with `(single)` in 2nd rule.

Comment: Oh no!! Hold on a second. I forgot to comment 2 lines further below. Just above my IP denial http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=t11fNZGY
I commented the line and now using the script as provided in your answer and it seems to work. Not having any such MyBB problems.
Many thanks